# Polar Coordinate Conversion (Integration)

Tags: transformation, polar-coordinates

I want to convert some integrals to use polar coordinates as my differentials, my problem is getting the limits.

So this is the first concept I am not understanding: 
If I have a circle in the xy-plane and want to represent it in polar coordinates with the restriction that the region is strictly everything on the right hand side of the line $x=1$ why would the lower limit be $1/\cos(\theta)$ if the circle I have is 
$ (x-1)^2 +y^2 = 1 $. I sort of understand how to get the upper limit but not the theory behind the lower. For the upper I simply expanded the $x$ terms to get $ r^2 = 2r*cos(\theta)$ and solved to get an upper limit of $2\cos(\theta)$

Please could someone explain the theory about the lower limit.

Answer (score 1):

the lower limit....
$x = r\cos\theta\\
y=r\sin\theta\\
x = 1\\
r\cos\theta=1\\
r = 1/\cos\theta$

I suggest until you have a solid intuition about these things, always sketch the curve.  Draw in some line $r = \theta$ and think about the value of $r$ at the endpoints of that line.

One more step, what are your limits for $\theta$?

$1/\cos\theta = 2\cos\theta\\
1/2 = \cos^2 \theta\\
\cos\theta = \sqrt2/2\\
\theta = -\pi/4,\pi/4$

How is it that we were able to discard $\cos\theta = -\sqrt2/2$?
I will leave that to you to think about.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to describe the red semi circle:

[image: The situation]
([Large Version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uwxAs.png))

This would mean $\theta \in [-\pi/4, \pi/4]$
and $r \in [\sqrt{2}, 2]$.

For the minimum $\theta=\pm \pi/4$ we have $\cos \theta = 1 / \sqrt{2} \iff \sqrt{2} = 1 / \cos \theta$.

Comment: yes thats correct , I understand the theta restrictions, not the distance (r) restrictions